# How to go back and forth between 2 destinations in compose navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am implementing a login system with Jetpack Compose and I'm using Compose Navigation. I have an "onboarding" screen where the user can choose whether they want to login or sign up. Fromn both the login and sign up screen the user can navigate to the other one, but let's say they keep navigating back and forth, then the back stack is full of those screens.

How should I handle the back stack in this case? I thought about checking if the destination is already present in the back stack and pop to that, but it looks like this has some pitfalls (the user could have visited one of those pages before and pop several destinations for example).

I'd also like to pop the whole login flow when done but I don't get how

Answer (score 0):

> How should I handle the back stack in this case? I thought about
> checking if the destination is already present in the back stack and
> pop to that

In a way you're right, but you don't need to do much of it yourself if you have circular navigation (this is what you describe). You can just use `popUpTo` from the signup page (if the login is supposed to be the "default" like such:

```
navController.navigate(loginRoute) {
    popUpTo(loginRoute) {
       inclusive = true
    }
}
```

The `inclusive = true` is necessary because you also want to pop the login from the stack itself:
If your stack looks like `AB` and you navigate back to `A`, you would pop just `B` and be left with AA (thus able to navigate back to A again while you're at A).

> I'd also like to pop the whole login flow when done but I don't get how

Similar to your initial idea, just pop the entire backstack after you're done using `navController.navigate(yourRoute) { popUpTo(0) }`